# Allowing simple footer customisation in settings?

Tags: 7

So, I want to give the client the ability to edit the footer, copyright & legal area. This isn't worth it's own content or block. I don't think....

Is is possible to add a text entry field into setting to customize the footer area or alike areas on the website.

Comment: Personally I think that's a pretty good use case for one or more blocks. If you're worried about the extra markup generated you can override the template for those (or all) blocks to strip out the extra stuff. I imagine your client will need to administer other blocks so it will give you a central location for editing those sorts of sections of the site, and help to keep the admin experience as consistent as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 6, the Site information settings page at /admin/settings/site-information has a "Footer Information" field that meets your description above.  If this field is not empty, and you do a major upgrade of your D6 site to D7, then your footer information will be moved into a block called "Footer message".  While it would be possible to re-implement the "Footer Information" field from D6 in D7 with a custom module, or in the settings for your theme (which would be even easier) I think it is clear that D7 designers felt that using a block for this purpose was the best and most general solution.